# How to automate specman files changes with python?

Tags: python, specman

I am working on a specman environment (hardware verification language), and I want to automate my tasks.

In order to do so, I learned Python programming with the target to use the file manipulation abilities. The problem is that I know only how to manipulate .txt files, Is there a way to change different kind of files?

Comment: you might have to write your own parser, but can you give more detail about what you are hoping to achieve?

Comment: Each project it is something else. Every project I'm working on is based on the one before, but some things are different. For instance, there could be a duplicate of the same hardware with a different address. I could go over the file and change it myself but I prefer to automate it. The information needed for the change exists in a different file (and I need to renew it, for example in the code coverage file). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is way too generic. It's possible to change *.e files using string matching, maybe in some cases this makes sense as a one-time task, but there couldn't be any rules for that. Writing e parser in python doesn't sound like a feasible task.

The only reasonable way to analyze e code is to load it and use reflection. But not always you can feed the results to python to let it make any meaningful modifications.

It's totally possible to use python to generate e code based on some formally defined specs, specifically mentioned coverage, generation constraints, etc. It can be efficient and maintainable approach. However, there are different facilities for that, including tables.

Python certainly can be used for all kinds of smart scriptology: define environment, track installations and versions, choose flows, generate stubs, etc.